# Reversing a word or sentence

Tags: java, performance, strings

Was just wanting some general feedback on the below code regarding
1. Readability
2. Structure
3. Efficiency

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections; 
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created on 5/27/2016.
 *
 * Simple functions used to reverse either a sentence or a word.
 */


public class Reverse {

    /**
     * The main function is used to retrieve user input and apply it to one of the
     * two reverse functions.
     * @param args Not used in this application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Gets user input.
        System.out.print(">>> ");
        String input = userInput.nextLine();

        if(input.contains(" ")) // If contains space its a sentence
            System.out.println(reverse(Arrays.asList(input.split(" "))));
        else
            System.out.println(reverse(input));
    }

    /**
     * Used to reverse the order of given list.
     * @param words The list of words that will be reversed then returned.
     * @return The result of the reversed parameter.
     */
    private static String reverse(List<String> words){
        Collections.reverse(words); // Reverses order of words.
        return String.join(" ", words);
    }

    /**
     * Used to reverse the order of a single word.
     * @param word The string word that will be loaded into a list one character at a time.
     * @return The result of the reversed parameter.
     */
    private static String reverse(String word){
        List<String> letters = Arrays.asList(word.split("")); // Stores each letter of word into list.
        Collections.reverse(letters); // Reverses the order of the list.
        return String.join("", letters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unfortunate that there are two `reverse()` functions that do similar things.  What is even more disconcerting is that they are inconsistent: `main()` is responsible for splitting a sentence into words, but `reverse(List<String> words)` joins them back up.  On the other hand, `reverse(String word)` doesn't work that way: it does both the splitting and joining.

Why not solve both problems consistently with one function?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Reverse {
    private Reverse() {}  // Suppress the default constructor

    /**
     * Splits the input on the delimiter, reverses the list, then joins the
     * results with the delimiter.
     */
    public static String reverse(String s, String delimiter) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter)));
        Collections.reverse(list);
        return String.join(delimiter, list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(">>> ");
        String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        if (input.contains(" ")) {
            // Reverse words in a sentence
            System.out.println(reverse(input, " "));
        } else {
            // Reverse characters in a word
            System.out.println(reverse(input, ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is a technicality, if `reverse()` is exposed as a public function as I have done.  In that case, you would expect it to work for any `delimiter`, so the delimiter must be quoted such that [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) treats it as a literal string rather than a regular expression.